# Compose different factors in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            Sensor            NewValue           NewDate
1   iphone/NuhKZFrx/noise     1.00000      2015-10-20 23:26:14
2   iphone/NuhKZFrx/noiseS    58.63411     2015-10-20 23:26:14
3   iphone/wlhAlrPQ/noise     0.00000      2015-10-21 08:03:28
4   iphone/wlhAlrPQ/noiseS    65.26167     2015-10-21 08:03:28
[...]
```

with the following datatypes:

```
'data.frame':   405 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Sensor  : Factor w/ 28 levels "iphone/5mZU0HWz/noise",..: 11 12 23 24 9 10 23 24 21 22 ...
 $ NewValue: num  1 58.6 0 65.3 3 ...
 $ NewDate : POSIXct, format: "2015-10-20 23:26:13" "2015-10-20 23:26:14" "2015-10-21 08:03:28" "2015-10-21 08:03:28" .
```

The Sensor field is set up like this: `<model>/<uniqueID>/<type>`. And I want to find out if there is a correlation between `noise` and `noiseS` for each `uniqueID` at a given time.

For a single `uniqueID` it works fine since there are only two factors. I tried to use `xtabs(NewValue~NewDate+Sensor, data=dataNoises)` but that gives me zeros since there aren't values for every ID at any time ...

What could I do to somehow compose the factors so that I only have on factor for `noise` and one for `noiseS`? Or is there an easier way to solve this problem?

What I want to do is the following:

```
Date                  noise        noiseS
2015-10-20 23:26:14     1           58.63
2015-10-20 23:29:10     4           78.33
```

And then compute the pearson correlation coefficient between noise and noiseS.

Comment: You should clarify your question. what do you mean by correlation here ? In the example below you have one row for each key(sensor,date) by type? Also in your data you have 2 dates which one to choose? Also your data are not easily readable ( see `dput` ) . Please Simplify the question , 1- easy input 2- expected output.

Comment: i updated the questions as you suggested! please let me know if i'm still missing something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want a 2-level factor that distinguishes between noise and noiseS?

That can be easily achieved by defining a new column in the dataframe and populating it with the output of grepl().  A MWE:

```
a <- "blahblahblahblahnoise"
aa <- "blahblahblahblahnoiseS"
b <- "noiseS"
type <- vector()
type[1] <- grepl(b, a)
type[2] <- grepl(b, aa)
type <- as.factor(type)
```

This two-level factor would let you build a simple model of the means for noise (`type[i]==FALSE`) and noiseS (`type[i]==TRUE`), but would not let you evaluate the CORRELATION between the types for a given UniqueID and time.  One way to do this would be to create separate columns for data with `type==FALSE` and `type==TRUE`, where rows correspond to a specific UniqueID+time combination.  In this case, you would need to think carefully about what you want to learn and when you assume data to be independent.  For example, if you want to learn whether noise and noiseS are correlated across time for a given uniqueID, then you would need to make a separate factor for uniqueID and include it in your model as an effect (possibly a random effect, depending on your purposes and your data).